# Unix bash shell script - Iterating an array in a 'for' loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following test script:

```
#!/bin/sh

testArray=(A,B,C,D,E)
currentValue=''
tempValue=x

for i in "${testArray[@]}"
    do
        currentValue=$i

        echo "Processing " ${currentValue}

        if [ ${currentValue}==A ]
        then
            tempValue="$i 123"
        else
            tempValue=$i
        fi

        echo "Current loop " ${tempValue} 
        echo `date`

    done
```

When i test it, the output that i get is

```
Processing  A,B,C,D,E
Current loop  A,B,C,D,E 123
Mon Dec 2 20:33:26 GMT 2013
```

It looks like the 'for' loop in Bash works somehow differently to what i am used to as i was expecting the following output (i.e. whatever is in the 'for' loop to be repeated for each of the array elements)

```
Processing  A
Current loop  A 123
Mon Dec 2 20:29:44 GMT 2013

Processing  B
Current loop  B
Mon Dec 2 20:29:45 GMT 2013

Processing  C
Current loop  C
Mon Dec 2 20:29:46 GMT 2013

Processing  D
Current loop  D
Mon Dec 2 20:29:47 GMT 2013

Processing  E
Current loop  E
Mon Dec 2 20:29:48 GMT 2013
```

- Why is the 123 at the end?
- Why is the date command executed only once and not for each iteration
- What do i do to make each iteration work correctly.

Basically what i am trying to achieve is to write a script that iterates through an array list and execute the same command based on different parameters dependent on the value of the current item in the array. I wrote the above script to try and understand how the for loop works but i am not getting the output i was expecting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line

```
testArray=(A,B,C,D,E)
```

creates an array with a single element, namely the string 'A,B,C,D,E'. Array elements are separated by whitespace, not commas. Use

```
testArray=(A B C D E)
```

---

You'll also need to add whitespace to your `if` statement (and technically, you should use `=` inside `[...]`, not `==`, as well as quote the parameter expansion):

```
if [ "${currentValue}" = A ]
```

Comment: ah got it.. i knew it would be something simple.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere this morning that a single '=' acts as an assignment.

Comment: Not inside a `test` expression. `bash` allows you to use `==` as a synonym for equality `=`, but it's not part of the POSIX specification.

Comment: @ziggy Tip: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/about.html) automatically points out both these issues and a few others

Answer (score 2):

One more way

Change your loop to:

```
for i in `echo ${testArray} | tr "," " "`
```

As Suggested by chepner Change conditional statement to:

```
if [ "${currentValue}" = A ]
```